# Include file from seperate domain on server: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, apache, ssh, plesk

I just upgraded Plesk to the latest version and it has caused many of my sites to go down.

The websites all rely on a file which is located on another domain on my server so they all host an index file which contains an include like this:

```
include('/var/www/vhosts/assets-domain.co.uk/httpdocs/websites/index.php');
```

I am getting the following error when viewing the website:

```
Warning: include(/var/www/vhosts/assets-domain.co.uk/httpdocs/websites/index.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/this-domain.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php on line 3 Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/vhosts/assets-domain.co.uk/httpdocs/websites/index.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /var/www/vhosts/this-domain.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php on line 3
```

So there is obviously a permissions problem of some sort but I have no idea where to start.

In SSH I have tried changing the ownership of the folder '/var/www/vhosts/assets-domain.co.uk/httpdocs/websites/' with no luck. I have noticed that all my domains have different ownership usernames now - would this affect it? EG.mydomain.com has the user of mydomain, cooldomain.com has the user of cooldomain - would this be why they can't access each others files?

Please help as I have 15+ websites down :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed this - Plesk decided to change the permissions so simply changing the domain name folder to 755 solved this

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me. Although I not quite understand why it is in the root directory of the domain where is needed to change the permissions to 755. I had tried to change in `<domain>/httpdocs` with no effect.